# How is register size and instruction encoding / operands related?

Tags: cpu, cpu-architecture

Example: a CPU has **x** registers and **y** bits of the instruction encoding is used to refer register operands. How many register operands can be specified in a single instruction? The architecture is unknown.

Is there a generic solution for this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This question is already generalized enough - you need to encode which registers you want the instruction to work on (using x86 as an example, `mov eax, ebx` needs 2 out of the total registers available in that architecture, `inc ecx` needs one).

You have x registers, so you'll need log2(x) bits to encode each of them. Since you're allowed only y bits for that, and you can encode at most floor(y/log2(x)) registers in a single instruction.

(Well, if you have spare bits you may still use them for partial encoding of something, but that's probably not what the question is testing...)

Comment: So if the total register count is for example 8:
log2(8) = 3 bits for each register.
And y bits is 8, so max is:
floor(8/log2(8)) = 2

How did you know to use the the binary logarithm and floor for this?
Thanks

Comment: since bits are binary, n bits can encode 2^n items, therefore the inverse is log2. The floor is because if you have extra 2 bits, you can't encode a third register. However, you can use them to encode something else (for e.g. memory addressing mode, or scale, etc..). But these things are architecture-specific, the question was generic.

Comment: To solve this type of calculations in the correct way (non architecture-specific) 
Do log2 on the number of registers to get how many bits each register is in size, this is the inverse of 2^n say for example in the 8 register case: 2^8 = 256, and log2(256) = 8
Use floor (number of registers / log2(bits of instruction encoding) to get maximum of register operands in a single instruction.

If the floor is taken away 8/log2(8) = 8/3 ( or 2.666...)
Having a hard time to understand the "extra 2 bits"

Thanks

Comment: Just ignore the remaining bits. Let's decide that we just can't do anything useful with them in the scope of the above question.